# Load RenderPartial on tab click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have some tabs and I want to call the RenderPartial, within the second tab, when the tab has been clicked (overviewTab).

Right now the RenderPartial loads when the page loads but I only want to load it when that overview tab is clicked. How can I accomplish this?

This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var overviewLoaded = false;
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#overviewTab').off('click').on('click', function() {
                if (!overviewLoaded) {
                    overviewLoaded = true;

                }
            });
</script>


<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a tabindex="0" target="_self" href="#edit" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Edit</a></li>
    <li id="overviewTab"><a tabindex="0" target="_self" href="#overview" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Account Overview</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="edit">
        // -- stuff
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="overview">
        <div class="row">
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("GetInfoPanel"); }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check about RenderPartialViewToString , and set html tab with that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to load the content of the overview tab via ajax when user clicks on the link for that tab.

So give an `Id` to the link and add an **html5 data attribute** to store the target url to load.

```
<li id="overviewTab">
 <a tabindex="0" target="_self"  id="overviewLink" href="#overviewLink" role="tab"
          data-url="@Url.Action("GetInfo","Home")"  data-toggle="tab">Account Overview</a>
</li>
```

and we will not make the `RenderPartial` call inside the tab content as we will load it with ajax.

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="edit">Edit Stuff</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="overview"></div>
</div>
```

Now using jQuery listen to the `click` event on this link and use jQuery `load()` method to asynchronously load the content of the overview tab.

```
$(function(){

     $("#overviewLink").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#profile").html("Loading...").load($(this).data("url"));
    });

});
```

Assuming you have an action method called GetInfo in your HomeController which returns the partial view for the Overview tab.

```
public ActionResult GetInfo()
{
  // to do : Update to include the data for the view
  return PartialView();
}
```

You can change the the jQuery selection from the Id based selection to a css class based selection if you want the above code to work for multiple tabs.

The above code makes an ajax call to the action method every time the link is clicked. You can add a little bit client side code to track which link is clicked and prevent the calls after the first call( *store in a local array which items are clicked and if it exists in the array ,don't make the call*)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to do this as you've asked. `Html.RenderPartial` happens on the server as part of the initial page request

The easiest thing to do would be to expose the html as a new ViewResult and then load it in via an ajax query when you want to display it

Answer (score 0):

Try using RenderPartialViewToString , and set html tab with that string. :

**Controller**

```
 [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetTab()
        {

            var msg = String.Empty;
            bool isValid = false;
            var view = String.Empty;

            try
            {
                var model = new Artist();
                model.Name = "Name";
                model.Band = "Band";
                view = RenderPartialViewToString("_ArtistDetail", model);
                isValid = true;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msg = String.Format("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), ex.Message);
                //or view = "Error" view
            }

            var result = new { isValid = isValid, view = view, msg = msg };
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        //Magic here!
        protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model = null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
                viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

            ViewData.Model = model;

            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

**Partial View  _ArtistDetail.cshtml**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Artist

<h1>@Model.Name</h1>
<h3>@Model.Band</h3>
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a tabindex="0" target="_self" href="#edit" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Edit</a></li>
    <li id="overviewTab"><a tabindex="0" target="_self" href="#overview" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Account Overview</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="edit">
        // -- stuff
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="overview">
        <div id="myTab" class="row">
            Loading...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        var target = $(e.target).attr("href");
        if (target == "#overview" && !overviewLoaded ) {
             GetTab();
            overviewLoaded  = true;
        };
    });

    var GetTab = function () {
        var div = $("#myTab");
        div.empty();
        div.append("Loading...");

        $.ajax({
            url: "/GetTab",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                div.empty();

                if (data.isValid) {
                    div.append(data.view);
                } else {
                    div.append(data.msg);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    };
```